# How to start server with "python manage.py runserver" whithout errors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, server, anaconda, startup

I installed Django with: `conda create --name myproject django`

Every check I made (environement, django, versions, etc) seems to be alright and I don't know what the problem is.

What I have:

```
(myproject) D:\@@@Work@@@\###INFORMATICA###\###PYTHON###\MySite>python -V
Python 3.7.3

(myproject) D:\@@@Work@@@\###INFORMATICA###\###PYTHON###\MySite>conda -V
conda 4.6.14


(myproject) D:\@@@Work@@@\###INFORMATICA###\###PYTHON###\MySite>conda 
list
 packages in environment at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject:

 Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
astroid                   2.2.5                    py37_0
ca-certificates           2019.1.23                     0
certifi                   2019.3.9                 py37_0
colorama                  0.4.1                    py37_0
django                    2.2                      py37_0
isort                     4.3.17                   py37_0
lazy-object-proxy         1.3.1            py37hfa6e2cd_2
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py37_1
openssl                   1.1.1b               he774522_1
pip                       19.1                     py37_0
pylint                    2.3.1                    py37_0
python                    3.7.3                h8c8aaf0_1
pytz                      2019.1                     py_0
setuptools                41.0.1                   py37_0
six                       1.12.0                   py37_0
sqlite                    3.28.0               he774522_0
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.15.26706          h3a45250_4
wheel                     0.33.1                   py37_0
wincertstore              0.2                      py37_0
wrapt                     1.11.1           py37he774522_0

(myproject) D:\@@@Work@@@\###INFORMATICA###\###PYTHON###\MySite> conda 
info --envs
conda environments:
base                     C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
myproject             *  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject

'# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 ]
```

And this is the output for : `python manage.py runserver`
(tried to add an IP and port but still no solution)

```
(myproject) D:\@@@Work@@@\###INFORMATICA###\###PYTHON###\MySite>python manage.py runserver

Watching for file changes with StatReloader Exception in thread Thread-1: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[0](_exception[1]).with_traceback(_exception[2])   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in
_call_with_frames_removed   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 117, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 204, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 201, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .introspection import DatabaseIntrospection            # isort:skip   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\introspection.py", line 4, in <module>
    import sqlparse ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlparse' Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 155, in get_app_config
    return self.app_configs[app_label] KeyError: 'admin' During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()   File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 579, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 564, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 272, in run
    get_resolver().urlconf_module   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 564, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in
_call_with_frames_removed   File "D:\@@@Work@@@\###INFORMATICA###\###PYTHON###\MySite\MySite\urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 256, in inner
    self._setup()   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 529, in _setup
    AdminSiteClass = import_string(apps.get_app_config('admin').default_site)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myproject\lib\site->packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 162, in get_app_config
    raise LookupError(message) LookupError: No installed app with label 'admin'.

(myproject) D:\@@@Work@@@\###INFORMATICA###\###PYTHON###\MySite
```

What could be the solution to the problem?

Comment: I don't know why you think this has anything to do with ports. The error says "No installed app with label 'admin'." So what is your INSTALLED_APPS setting?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the traceback with code format (`{}` button). It is unreadable as a quote.

Comment: # Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

Answer (score 0):

I found out an answer.
It seems that `conda` package manager is not working properly on my windows 10 installation.
The solution is to install with `pip` package manager.

With the virtual environement active the command is:

```
pip install django --force
```

Hope that no one will spend so much time, to figure out a verry simple solution.
Ceers!